# Moving Infopath form from dev to QC

Tags: infopath

I developed an infopath form in dev and it's ready to be moved to QC. How do I do that? I tried opening it with infopath designer and did not see any option to change the main data connection to qc instead of dev.

please suggest.

Comment: Anyone on this please? running out of time. need to meet deadline.

Comment: Is this a SharePoint Form Library or SharePoint List? See you are talking about you cant change main data connection, im guessing its a SharePoint List template. Those are basically bound to the list and url. You could always save the list as a template and create the list on other severs with the new infopath form iirc

Comment: It's bound to a list. So Save the list as a template and then deploy the in qc or prod. then create a list based on that list and the info path form should come with it. is that what you are saying?

Comment: Found a blog post that could help you: http://kumartechnotes.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/deploying-sharepoint-2010-list-custom-infopath-form-to-different-site/

Answer (score 1):

Moving an InfoPath form a development environment to a QA environment always is not so straight forward. It depends based on the data connections that you have established and if the data connections submit or receive data to external web services or sql databases it would be more difficult.

Two things could help you in deploying InfoPath forms to different enviorments

1. While creating a data connection to submit or receive data from SharePoint, use `http://localhost:port/` in the development machine, so that using the same form in any other farm would work. Just make sure that the port number is same throughout.
2. Use Data connection library while using InfoPath data connections. The .udcx files can be uploaded into a central data connection library in a SharePoint site which can be pushed to different environments easily.

Answer (score 0):

Deepu is right, depending data connections it could be slightly difficult to do. I have been fortunate with the projects I worked on are InfoPath forms published to a form library usually contained within a site collection.

When our site admin moves the site, I usually have to republish the form from InfoPath. One of the last options in this wizard asks you if you want to update any data connections associated with the form.

Afterwards I double check these to make sure they are pointing to the new locations of the migrated sources.