# Created a Local Infopath form but need to attached to a SP List

Tags: infopath

I created a local InfoPath 2010 form. On the submit option I see doc lib. But I need to attached this form to a list.

How is it done?

Comment: I havn't done that much of infopath form. As I understood if you create a infopath from scratch (meaning without going through sharepoint list UI, where you can create create a tightly coupled infopath form) then you may need to use form library to host your infopath form. I think there is another way to utilize using content type. I wish I had good concrete answer. I am SURE there are pros here who can guide you to the proper steps and provide some good links.

Comment: Can anyone please shed any light on this? I need to be able to use this new form in 4 different stages (dev, qc, test and prod).

Answer (score 1):

Attach the InfoPath form to a SharePoint List? Do you mean publishing an InfoPath form within a SharePoint list? Then follow the below steps

1. Create a custom list
2. Enable the site collection and site feature for Infopth Form services.
3. Go to the custom list -> List settings -> Customize the list using InfoPath form.
4. Once completed editing the form, publish it and then the list will be opened in an InfoPath UI.

Please [visit this blog](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/customizing-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-infopath-2010) to have a detailed view on how this is done.

Or if you need to customize the New / Edit / View forms in list using InfoPath, [follow this post.](http://blog.libinuko.com/2010/03/21/sharepoint-2010-howto-start-customize-list-form-neweditview-using-infopath-designer-2010/)

Comment: Thanks for the steps. But this way I have to repeat the steps 4 times (with all the complex logics, rules, submit, adding web services, etc.) for four different environments.

Comment: It depends... The more complex your InfoPath form, the more tweaking you will have to do in all the environments. By default if you are taking a site backup and restore in each env., it should bring everything necessary for the form. Please check this link where I have answered a similar question. It should give you some more insight.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30264/moving-infopath-form-from-dev-to-qc/30454#30454 .But if you try to detail how complex your InfoPath can be, then I could guide you specifically.